# Installing PHP SDK Couchbase error

Tags: php, couchbase

I'm trying to install the PHP SDK for my Couchbase cluster and everything during installation finishes without a hitch, but when I run `php -i` in the terminal I get the following error:

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library
>   '/usr/lib/php5/20121212/couchbase.so' -
>   /usr/lib/php5/20121212/couchbase.so: undefined symbol:
>   php_json_decode_ex in Unknown on line 0

I don't understand why the couchbase extension won't load.

My setup is:

Ubuntu Server 14.04
Couchbase Server Enterprise 4.5.1

I followed this guide for setting up PHP SDK:

[Link to PHP SDK installation guide](http://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/4.5/sdk/php/start-using-sdk.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Enable extension=json.so in your php.ini if it is not enabled. If it is, enable the couchbase extension after the json extension.

As said in the couchbase php sdk [documentation](https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/4.5/sdk/php/start-using-sdk.html)

> The Couchbase SDK depends on the JSON PHP extension, so make sure that load order is correct. For example, if your distribution has just a single php.ini file, just insert the line after extension=json.so. If your distribution uses a conf.d-style, name the file with the Couchbase SDK ini so that it will be alphabetically ordered after the JSON extension.

Comment: Hi, I tested what you said and it worked perfectly. Now when I run phpinfo() couchbase gets loaded.

Thanks for your very quick answer!